# df.loc - ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 0)

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have the following code - I am trying to get a matching row in one dataframe based on the `Last Name` column.

```py
def rule(row):
    name = row['Last Name']
    return rules.loc[rules['Last Name'] == name]['Type']

df['Type'] = df.apply(rule, axis=1)
```

When I run this I get an error, because of the `== name` in the `rule` method - how do I fix it?

```
ValueError: ('Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 0)', 'occurred at index 0')
```

This is what `rules` looks like:

```
  Last Name      Type
0     Smith         A
1     Doe           B
```

and `df`:

```
             Name First Name Last Name
0      John Smith      John      Smith
1        Jane Doe      Jane      Doe
2        John Doe      John      Doe
```

I want the final to look like:

```
             Name First Name Last Name  Type
0      John Smith      John      Smith     A
1        Jane Doe      Jane      Doe       B
2        John Doe      John      Doe       B
```

EDIT: Added example `rules` and `df`

Comment: please provide some input data and your expected result

Comment: @splash58 I get the same error when I try that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'First Name': ['John', 'Jane','John'], 'Last Name': ['Smith','Doe','Doe']})
print(df1)

rules = pd.DataFrame({'Last Name':['Smith', 'Doe'], 'Type': ['A','B']})
print(rules)
```

Output is:

```
    First Name Last Name
0       John     Smith 
1       Jane       Doe
2       John       Doe
   Last Name Type
0     Smith    A
1       Doe    B
```

df1.merge(rules)

output is:

```
    First Name  Last Name   Type
0       John    Smith   A
1       Jane    Doe     B
2       John    Doe     B
```

is it your desire answer?

Comment: Yes, but I am getting an error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'Array'` - the `dtype` of each row appears to be `object`

Comment: It worked. I had to convert the automatic types from `read_excel` to `str`